# Can we set watermark text as background?

Tags: javascript, html, watermark

Can we set water mark text as it like background text for watermark

```
<p style='position:fixed; color: #d0d0d0;font-size: 70pt;-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);left:center;'>Test Water mark</p>
```

if I give `z-index: -1` to `< p >` , text not visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text at -1 is not visible if you have a background defined at 0 or higher. Thus, to see everything, you need at least two "layers": a background layer (at a lower Z, say -1) which will also contain your watermark, and a higher layer (say 0) which will *not* have a background (or will have a non-opaque background) and will contain your foreground.

What I suspect you did is have a foreground+background element with the default Z of 0; in this scenario you cannot insert a watermark between them, as there *is no between*; so your watermark either covers the foreground, or is behind the background (and thus invisible).

Answer (score 0):

add below given style to < P > tag

```
width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: grey; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    zoom: 1; 
    opacity: 0.4; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
```